# How to get all the dependencies using NPM for your Angular Application

Tags: javascript, gulp

i have installed NPM

also i had saved it as given in GIT[showing the result after npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EltnP.jpg)

and i even installed gulp and when i checked its not been installed[gulp error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vfOP.jpg)

**The template that i downloaded reads as follows : **

    
     to automaticaly populate bower styles dependencies -->

```
<!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
<!-- inject:css -->
<!-- css files will be automaticaly insert here -->
```

**in the body section :**

```
<!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- run `gulp wiredep` to automaticaly populate bower script dependencies -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- js files will be automaticaly insert here -->
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- inject:partials -->
<!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

**and finally i tried cashing everything i supposed to be relevant in my localhost but again it failed to run.**

Comment: I suggest adding the images inline

Comment: @PaulBastide Adding images inline is above my 'Reputation Scale'

Comment: The problem was solved. There was a clash with the Npm version which was preventing the bower installations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to initialize your working directory: `npm init`.
Do the same for bower.

When you install a package with `npm` you can pass `--save` or `--save-dev` as parameters so `npm` will track the name and the version of the package in the `package.json` file.This allow to any one who clone your repo to run `npm install` and get all the packages been listed on the `package.json` file. If you want to use bower then you need to install it with `npm install bower --save-dev` and then install packages the same way as with `npm`. e.g: `bower install jquery -S`. So `bower` will track the dependencies of your project on a `bower.json` file. It is posible to add a `preinstall` and `postinstall` key on the `scripts` section of the `package.json` file so npm will run the those commands before of after installing your dependencies:

//package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  }
}
```

To replace the scripts and links styles you'll need to create a task on your gulp file

Comment: I think i was missing more than Postinstall in the package.json
thaks @raulucco